# Show that $ P\left\{\lim_{t\to 0}X_t=0\right\}=P\left\{ \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \bigcup_{m\geq 1}\bigcap_{t\in]0,1/m[}|X_t|\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to show that 
 $$\mathbb P\left\{\lim_{t\to 0^+}X_t=0\right\}=\mathbb P\left\{\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{m\geq 1}\bigcap_{t\in]0,1/m[}|X_t|\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\}.$$
Since $$\mathbb P\left\{\lim_{t\to 0^+}X_t=0\right\}=\mathbb P\left\{\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}\bigcup_{\delta>0}\bigcap_{0<t<\delta}|X_t|<\varepsilon\right\},$$

the inclusion $$\left\{\lim_{t\to 0^+}X_t=0\right\}\subset\left\{\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{m\geq 1}\bigcap_{t\in]0,1/m[}|X_t|\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\},$$
is obvious, and thus 
$$\mathbb P\left\{\lim_{t\to 0^+}X_t=0\right\}\leq\mathbb P\left\{\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{m\geq 1}\bigcap_{t\in]0,1/m[}|X_t|\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\}.$$
But I really have problem for the converse inequality. Any idea ?

Comment: This is a deterministic result: $x(t)\to c$ when $t\to0^+$ means exactly that $$\forall n\quad \exists m\quad \forall t\quad 0<t<\frac1m\implies|x(t)-c|\leqslant\frac1n$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\omega \in \left\{\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{m\geq 1}\bigcap_{t\in]0,1/m[}|X_t|\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\}$$

This means that, for all $n \geq 1$, there exists $m\geq 1$ such that for all $t \in ]0,1/m[$, $|X_t( \omega)| \leq 1/n$.

This implies that $\lim_{t \to 0^+} X_t(\omega) = 0$.

The rest should be immediate.