# How to show that $\{ \lim\limits_{k} ~X_k \leq x\} = \bigcap_{\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^+}\bigcup_{K}\bigcap_{k \geq K} \{X_k < x+\varepsilon \}$?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

In one of my exercises, the solution uses another way to describe the limit.
We have a sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2,...$
$$\{ \lim\limits_{k} ~X_k \leq x\} = \bigcap_{\varepsilon  \in \mathbb{Q}^+}\bigcup_{K}\bigcap_{k \geq K} \{X_k < x+\varepsilon  \}$$

Can anyone explain it to me?
I know that for example: $\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} ~X_n = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \bigcap_{k \geq n} X_k$

So why is $\lim$ defined like this?

Comment: It is not another way to denote "limit" but another way to write a "set".

Comment: The "example" you know is for "sets", not for random variables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Sequences_of_sets

Comment: This question has a similar flavor: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2049719/9464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\{ \lim_nX_n\leqslant x\}$ then $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N},$   such that $X_n - \lim_n X_n < \epsilon , \forall n \geqslant n_0 \Rightarrow $ $X_n < \lim_nX_n + \epsilon \leqslant x+ \epsilon$.

Thus $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N},$ such that $X_n<x+ \epsilon , \forall n \geqslant n_0 \Rightarrow x \in \bigcap_{\epsilon>0} \bigcup_{n_0 \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \geqslant n_0} \{X_n<x+ \epsilon\}=B$.

Now let $x   \in B= \bigcap_{\epsilon>0} \bigcup_{n_0 \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n \geqslant n_0} \{X_n<x+ \epsilon\}$, thus  $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N},$ such that $X_n<x+ \epsilon , \forall n \geqslant n_0 \Rightarrow \limsup X_n \leqslant x \Rightarrow \lim_nX_n \leqslant x$ thus $x \in A$.

The trick here is to interpret the quantifiers $\exists, \forall$ as union and intersection respectively.

Also form your post i assumed that the limit of $X_n$ exists that's why i passed from limsup to the limit of $X_n$

Answer (score 1):

Wlog $\epsilon\in \mathbb Q^+.$

Now if we parse $S:=\bigcap_{\varepsilon  \in \mathbb{Q}^+}\bigcup_{K}\bigcap_{k \geq K} \{X_k < x+\epsilon  \}$ we have, step by step:

$1). x\in S$ if and only if $x\in S_K=\bigcup_{K}\bigcap_{k \geq K} \{X_k < x+\epsilon  \} \ \textit {for each}\  \epsilon\in \mathbb Q^+  $

$2). x\in S_K$ if and only if there is an integer $K$ such that $x\in \bigcap_{k \geq K} \{X_k < x+\epsilon  \} $ and this happens if and only if

$3).\ x\in \textit {each of }\ \{X_K < x+\epsilon  \},\{X_{K+1} < x+\epsilon  \},\cdots .$

Combining $1), 2), 3)$ we have $x\in S$ if and only if for each $\epsilon\in \mathbb Q^+  ,$ there is an integer $K$ such that $X_k\le x+\epsilon  $ whenever $k\ge K.$ But this implies that $\lim X_k\le x$ and so $x\in \{ \lim\limits_{k} ~X_k \leq x\}.$

A similar argument shows that $x\in \{ \lim\limits_{k} ~X_k \leq x\}\Rightarrow x\in S$ and therefore that $\{ \lim\limits_{k} ~X_k \leq x\}=S.$